# .htaccess issue and console issue in live --prod build in angular 6 app

Tags: .htaccess, build, angular6, console.log

I have two issue in my angular app.

**Issue 1: .htaccess issue**

In my case , I have setup my app on EC2 instance.

Path is ::: **var/www/html/adminpanel**

I have set this `.htaccess` file. I put this file in `adminpanel` folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /adminpanel/index.html [NC,L]
```

Now it works fine, but when I reload page I got **Not Found** error. 
[image: Not found URL image]

**Issue 2: I'm not able to remove console.log in prod build.**

I have make a build using this command.

`ng build --prod`

In `main.ts` file I have set this code.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  if(window){
    window.console.log=function(){};
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```